# Finding a planes equation containing a specific curve

Tags: calculus

What is the algorithm if I wanna fond a planes equation that contains a specific curve in space (a continuous curve $\gamma(t)$)?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Assuming the curve is not a straight line, identify three points on the curve. Can you find the plane through 3 points?

Comment: but how can I be sure it's contain the whole curve ? and not only these three points ? , Is it necessary that by random three points I will get the only specific plain contains this curve (Is it because three points not on same line define one plain) ? thanks.

Comment: If your curve is sitting in one plane then any three points not on the same straight line will do. Of course, if your curve is not in one plane (like a helix for example) then the question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above, try to find a plane equation by picking up 3 random points, then you have an equation.
Then put your curve into the plane equation, if what you have is 0=0, your curve is on the plane, if not only a point or a part is on it.

Likewise, consider (1+t, 2-t, 3t) line to begin with, one plane that you can guess is x+z+4y-9=0, when you put this line into the equation, you will see that any point on the line will hold, which means it lies on that plane.

You can make some ideas out of this:
Let your plane be Ax+By+Cz+D=0,
and let your curve be (f(t), g(t), h(t))
If f,g,h are linearly dependent, there is always a plane.
If all of them are linearly independent, you are going to have to pick A=B=C=0, which will force D=0, so you won't have a plane.

Hope this helps.